# CORS GET request in jQuery

Tags: jquery, cors

I'm trying to make a core request that should return a bunch of json data, however for some reason the request fails. The code I've done so far is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var url = 'http://test/v/calls';
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    beforeSend: function (request) {
        request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer test");
    },
    success: function (json) {
        console.log("Success", json);
    },
    error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
});
```

The response is as follows:

```
catcher.js:197 OPTIONS http://test/v/calls 401 (Unauthorized)
```

And:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://test/v/calls. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://some_domain' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

Note: the same url with the authorization parameters work fine with in Postman. Can't see what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable cors on the server. It works in Postman because of the way that postman's protocol handles cross-site-scripting. What is your server built on? And how do you add cors to your endpoints? are two questions you could start with.

Comment: I've added: `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` in vhost.conf according to this post: [link](https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html). After that I've run the command `ln -sf /etc/apache2/mods-available/headers.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/headers.load`.Still the response I get is the same.

Comment: I've debugged a bit and I found this: `Www-Authenticate:Bearer realm="api"`. Where does that come from? Should it not be test?